# Amplify hasMany with authentication

Tags: aws-amplify

I am working with amplify on a project and have difficulty getting one thing the way I want. Not sure is it at this time a matter of me not understanding the tool, or something is missing.
I would like to have  2 tables, with hasMany relation, A hasMany B. I would like to add a security on top of that so only owner of row in table A can access rows in table B that belong to his row in A. Is this possible? I tried some combinations with hasMany and auth but got nowhere.

Additionally I expected that if I create a row in table B with reference to row in table A, I will see it while performing a listA, however it's just empty.

I Appreciate help

Comment: This might help you if you're going to use GraphQL API, https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/connection/

Comment: unfortunately I can't find any doc or blog about aws graphql data modeling V2 , the official doc is very poor  and unclear ,